# OneToMany mapping not working in Spring Boot + Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I am working on Spring Boot + Hibernate application. I wanted to know how I can save OneToMany relationship including the foreign key as well.

I have 2 classes Employee and Address that has OneToMany relationship.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int empId;
    private String name;
    private String designation;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }
}


@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int addressID;
    private String city;
    private String country;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "empId")
    private Employee employee;

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }
}
```

Dao Code :

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Employee save(Employee employee) {
        Session session = getSession();
        session.persist(employee);      
        return employee;

    }

    private Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

When I am trying to save data using json Post request as :

```
{
  "name": "Kamal Verma",
  "designation": "SAL1",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "city": "Noida",
      "country": "India"
    }
  ]
}
```

Its working fine without any error but in database in Address table EMPID is null.

Kindly, please let me know what I am doing wrong as foreign key in Address table is not getting saved.

Thanks,
Kamal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the 'employee' field in your Address class.

Update the setter in your Employee class to:

```
public void setAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
    this.addresses.clear();

    for (Address address: addresses) {
      address.setEmployee(this);
      this.addresses.add(address);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kishan, Thanks alot for your suggestion. It worked. Just wanted to know after posting this question I also found out the solution for this by changing the service as                                                                   
                public Employee save(Employee employee) {
  Set<Address> addresses = employee.getAddresses();
  for (Address address : addresses) {
   address.setEmployee(employee);
  }
  return dao.save(employee);

 }  So, wanted to check what should be the best practise to put this in Pojo or on service.

Comment: I prefer to put it in the POJO because that guarantees the Address employee field will always be set - just in case you are saving the employee elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 0):

Before saving the Employee object, All address objects has to set the employ reference so then hibernate can populate empId in address tale.

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public Employee save(Employee employee) {
    Session session = getSession();
    for(Address address: employee.getAddresses()){
        address.setEmployee(employee); //Set employee to address.
    }
    session.persist(employee);      
    return employee;

}

private Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```